# Adwords api: CPC, how to set "raise to estimated first page bid"

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I am developing a software in **PHP** to set campaigns with automatic bids on **Google Adword**s. I can't find a way to set the "**raise to estimated first page bid**", which is present in the UI.

I can set a max cpc but can't set these other options, an other is "raise to estimated top of page bid". What I want is, let Google choose the optimal bid for my ad to reach the first page, and I want to do it with PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [PageOnePromotedBiddingScheme](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/BiddingStrategyService.PageOnePromotedBiddingScheme).

For some ideas on how to use it, see the [examples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201702/AdvancedOperations/UsePortfolioBiddingStrategy.php), especially the `createBiddingStrategy` function—just replace the `TargetSpendBiddingScheme` which is instantiated there with the bidding scheme you'd like to use.